# Kill child process with WaitForExit() when parent process closes

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

I have a c# .netcore application which is interacting with an external command-line-based program (let's call it `program.exe`), through StandardOutput and StandardInput. `program.exe` will run forever unless it is specifically told to close (by sending `exit` to StandardInput).

The issue is that I need this program to close when mine does (no matter how), but I also need to call `Process.WaitForExit()` after it has started, in order to flush the output buffer, and actually receive the program's output. I'm therefore also running this entire operation in a separate thread, so that `WaitForExit()` doesn't block the rest of my application.

Here's a slighly simplified example of what's going on:

```cs
public static class BackgroundProcess
{
    //Called by my application to start the associated process in a new thread
    public static void Start()
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(RunBackgroundProcess);
        worker.IsBackground = true;
        worker.Start();
    }
    static Process backgroundProcess;
    public static void RunBackgroundProcess()
    {
        backgroundProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "program.exe",
                Arguments = "start",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            }
        }
        backgroundProcess.OutputDataReceived += BackgroundProcess_OutputDataReceived;
        backgroundProcess.Start();
        backgroundProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        backgroundProcess.WaitForExit(); //required in order to flush the output buffer
    }
    private static void BackgroundProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoStuffWithData(e.Data);
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, it's a combination of starting the process in a separate thread and the `.WaitForExit()` which is keeping `program.exe` open after my application closes: How can I either flush the output buffer without using `.WaitForExit()`, or ensure that it's still killed when my application is?

Also please note that this application needs to remain compatible with macOS and Linux, in addition to Windows.

Comment: Flushing the output buffer is not something you do, it is what the program does.  That buffer lives inside the program.  Nothing you can do to encourage it, you must keep your program running until you got a reliable signal that it terminated to ensure you'll get everything.  Either with WaitForExit() or the Exited event, the latter helps a lot to avoid having to create a thread and greatly simplifies the code you have to write to ensure your program stays active.  If it does not terminate then you need to find out why, not redirecting StandardError is one obvious reason in the snippet.